# Why doesn't Scipy's wasserstein_distance use linear programming?

Tags: statistics, linear-programming, python, programming, optimal-transport

#### Question

Kantorovich's formulation of the optimal transport problem using the **Wasserstein distance** is

$$\begin{align}\begin{aligned}W_p(a,b)=(\min_\gamma \sum_{i,j}\gamma_{i,j}\|x_i-y_j\|_p)^\frac{1}{p}\\s.t. \gamma 1 = a; \gamma^T 1= b; \gamma\geq 0\end{aligned}\end{align}$$

It is often taught that this is solved using linear programming:

$$\begin{align}\begin{aligned}OT(a,b)=\min_\gamma \quad \sum_{i,j}\gamma_{i,j}M_{i,j}\\s.t. \gamma 1 = a; \gamma^T 1= b; \gamma\geq 0\end{aligned}\end{align}$$

How then is the function `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance` able to solve Wasserstein/OT *without* linear programming? What approach/method is the function using?

#### My guess

I am aware that `wasserstein_distance` is for 1D distributions only, and there so happens to be a closed-form analytical solution in the 1D case which is

$$\mathcal{W}_{p}(\mu, \nu) =\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left|F_{\mu}^{-1}(z)-F_{\nu}^{-1}(z)\right|^{p} \mathrm{d} z\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$

The formula above contains **inverse probability functions** $F^{-1}$. The code, shown next, however, does not contain inverse probability functions from what I can see.

#### Code

I know this sounds like a stackoverflow question, but it's not (and I need to write the math formulas): I'm trying to figure out what formula/approach is being used by the code since the code does not resemble anything above: It doesn't use linear programming, otherwise we would see `scipy.optimize.linprog` somewhere, and it doesn't use inverse probability, otherwise we would see `.ppf` somewhere:

```
def wasserstein_distance(u_values, v_values, u_weights=None, v_weights=None):
    r"""
    Compute the first Wasserstein distance between two 1D distributions.
    This distance is also known as the earth mover's distance, since it can be
    seen as the minimum amount of "work" required to transform :math:`u` into
    :math:`v`, where "work" is measured as the amount of distribution weight
    that must be moved, multiplied by the distance it has to be moved.
    .. versionadded:: 1.0.0
    Parameters
    ----------
    u_values, v_values : array_like
        Values observed in the (empirical) distribution.
    u_weights, v_weights : array_like, optional
        Weight for each value. If unspecified, each value is assigned the same
        weight.
        `u_weights` (resp. `v_weights`) must have the same length as
        `u_values` (resp. `v_values`). If the weight sum differs from 1, it
        must still be positive and finite so that the weights can be normalized
        to sum to 1.
    Returns
    -------
    distance : float
        The computed distance between the distributions.
    Notes
    -----
    The first Wasserstein distance between the distributions :math:`u` and
    :math:`v` is:
    .. math::
        l_1 (u, v) = \inf_{\pi \in \Gamma (u, v)} \int_{\mathbb{R} \times
        \mathbb{R}} |x-y| \mathrm{d} \pi (x, y)
    where :math:`\Gamma (u, v)` is the set of (probability) distributions on
    :math:`\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}` whose marginals are :math:`u` and
    :math:`v` on the first and second factors respectively.
    If :math:`U` and :math:`V` are the respective CDFs of :math:`u` and
    :math:`v`, this distance also equals to:
    .. math::
        l_1(u, v) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |U-V|
    See [2]_ for a proof of the equivalence of both definitions.
    The input distributions can be empirical, therefore coming from samples
    whose values are effectively inputs of the function, or they can be seen as
    generalized functions, in which case they are weighted sums of Dirac delta
    functions located at the specified values.
    References
    ----------
    .. [1] "Wasserstein metric", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric
    .. [2] Ramdas, Garcia, Cuturi "On Wasserstein Two Sample Testing and Related
           Families of Nonparametric Tests" (2015). :arXiv:`1509.02237`.
    Examples
    --------
    >>> from scipy.stats import wasserstein_distance
    >>> wasserstein_distance([0, 1, 3], [5, 6, 8])
    5.0
    >>> wasserstein_distance([0, 1], [0, 1], [3, 1], [2, 2])
    0.25
    >>> wasserstein_distance([3.4, 3.9, 7.5, 7.8], [4.5, 1.4],
    ...                      [1.4, 0.9, 3.1, 7.2], [3.2, 3.5])
    4.0781331438047861
    """
    return _cdf_distance(1, u_values, v_values, u_weights, v_weights)

def _cdf_distance(p, u_values, v_values, u_weights=None, v_weights=None):
    r"""
    Compute, between two one-dimensional distributions :math:`u` and
    :math:`v`, whose respective CDFs are :math:`U` and :math:`V`, the
    statistical distance that is defined as:
    .. math::
        l_p(u, v) = \left( \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |U-V|^p \right)^{1/p}
    p is a positive parameter; p = 1 gives the Wasserstein distance, p = 2
    gives the energy distance.
    Parameters
    ----------
    u_values, v_values : array_like
        Values observed in the (empirical) distribution.
    u_weights, v_weights : array_like, optional
        Weight for each value. If unspecified, each value is assigned the same
        weight.
        `u_weights` (resp. `v_weights`) must have the same length as
        `u_values` (resp. `v_values`). If the weight sum differs from 1, it
        must still be positive and finite so that the weights can be normalized
        to sum to 1.
    Returns
    -------
    distance : float
        The computed distance between the distributions.
    Notes
    -----
    The input distributions can be empirical, therefore coming from samples
    whose values are effectively inputs of the function, or they can be seen as
    generalized functions, in which case they are weighted sums of Dirac delta
    functions located at the specified values.
    References
    ----------
    .. [1] Bellemare, Danihelka, Dabney, Mohamed, Lakshminarayanan, Hoyer,
           Munos "The Cramer Distance as a Solution to Biased Wasserstein
           Gradients" (2017). :arXiv:`1705.10743`.
    """
    u_values, u_weights = _validate_distribution(u_values, u_weights)
    v_values, v_weights = _validate_distribution(v_values, v_weights)

    u_sorter = np.argsort(u_values)
    v_sorter = np.argsort(v_values)

    all_values = np.concatenate((u_values, v_values))
    all_values.sort(kind='mergesort')

    # Compute the differences between pairs of successive values of u and v.
    deltas = np.diff(all_values)

    # Get the respective positions of the values of u and v among the values of
    # both distributions.
    u_cdf_indices = u_values[u_sorter].searchsorted(all_values[:-1], 'right')
    v_cdf_indices = v_values[v_sorter].searchsorted(all_values[:-1], 'right')

    # Calculate the CDFs of u and v using their weights, if specified.
    if u_weights is None:
        u_cdf = u_cdf_indices / u_values.size
    else:
        u_sorted_cumweights = np.concatenate(([0],
                                              np.cumsum(u_weights[u_sorter])))
        u_cdf = u_sorted_cumweights[u_cdf_indices] / u_sorted_cumweights[-1]

    if v_weights is None:
        v_cdf = v_cdf_indices / v_values.size
    else:
        v_sorted_cumweights = np.concatenate(([0],
                                              np.cumsum(v_weights[v_sorter])))
        v_cdf = v_sorted_cumweights[v_cdf_indices] / v_sorted_cumweights[-1]

    # Compute the value of the integral based on the CDFs.
    # If p = 1 or p = 2, we avoid using np.power, which introduces an overhead
    # of about 15%.
    if p == 1:
        return np.sum(np.multiply(np.abs(u_cdf - v_cdf), deltas))
    if p == 2:
        return np.sqrt(np.sum(np.multiply(np.square(u_cdf - v_cdf), deltas)))
    return np.power(np.sum(np.multiply(np.power(np.abs(u_cdf - v_cdf), p),
                                       deltas)), 1/p)
```

Comment: What you've written down is not the generic form of the Wasserstein metric $W_{p}(\mu,\nu)$ between two probability measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ but already the special case when taking discrete measures $\mu=\sum a_{i}\delta_{x_{i}}$ and $\nu=\sum b_{j}\delta_{y_{j}}$. Then the way to your matrix optimization problem is fairly simple. Set $M_{i,j}:=\|x_{i}-y_{j}\|^{2}$.

Comment: I still don't quite understand the usage of Dirac deltas in OT to be honest or what they are. But isn't my matrix specification closer to the linear programming implementation of OT than yours, with yours looking matrix-less and more like the plain old Wasserstein distance. It looks like you just want backwards from my second formula to the first formula

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more complete explanation for the algorithm used is in Remark 2.28 of the book Computational Optimal Transport. But a brief explanation of how the algorithm works is the following:

We are dealing with a 1-D case with two Discrete distributions where we want to transport $\alpha$ to $\beta$. Now, you sort the distribution and from left to right, you move each mass of $\beta$ to the closest mass of $\alpha$ until that mass is completely transported. The figure is from the book and illustrates this.
[image]

Comment: so `wasserstein_distance` is not an implementation of $$
\mathcal{W}_{p}(\mu, \nu) =\left(\int_{0}^{1}\left|F_{\mu}^{-1}(z)-F_{\nu}^{-1}(z)\right|^{p} \mathrm{d} z\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}?$$

Comment: It’s equivalent, in the sense that you get the same distance. But you can construct an optimal map by this greedy algorithm I just described.

Comment: Remark 2.28 looks like the transport matrix is completely omitted then. only the distances are imputed

Comment: Note that the $\sigma$ in the image is the optimal map. And hence you can just compute it’s cost to get the Wasserstein distance.

Comment: In the algorithm, you can move each chunk of mass, calculate the cost for each movement and sum, to get the total cost. There is no need to store the map, unless you want to for some reason.

Comment: Just be careful with equation 2.33 of the Remark 2.28. In that case, he is talking about distribution with identical mass in each point.

Comment: and this still works even if the source distribution's coordinates have a domain of $[-0.2,0.05]$, while the target's is $[0.03,0.10]$ (financial returns data)?

Comment: Yeah, sure. No restrictions in that regard. The support need not match

Comment: Equation 2.33 was what I was talking about. the transport plan/matrix is absent there. what would be the equation then for non-identical mass? just the transport plan returned to its place?

Comment: Not sure if it would be anything neat as the formula he wrote. Probably something messy, with lot’s of indicator functions.

Comment: "identical mass in each point" sounds like the uniform distribution?

Comment: Discrete uniform, yes

Comment: I struggle to lift the `wasserstein_distance` code to math formulas, and wonder where Peyre and Cuturi sourced the 1D algorithm that they skim over in Remark 2.28. `np.sum(np.multiply(np.abs(u_cdf - v_cdf), deltas))` reads alot like distances (`np.abs(u_cdf - v_cdf)`) multiplied by distances (`deltas = np.diff(all_values)`), when it actually should be distances multiplied by *amounts*. The coding of the "search for" the most optimal transport plan isn't readily apparent anywhere