# Different linear programming versions of optimal transport

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, optimization, linear-programming, optimal-transport

What is the difference between these two different versions of the linear programming optimization set-up for optimal transport (OT)?  how to reconcile them mathematically to show that they are equivalent?

### OT Linear Programming #1

([Source](https://dfdazac.github.io/sinkhorn.html))
\begin{align*}
\min_{\boldsymbol\Gamma} \quad & \langle\mathbf{C},\boldsymbol\Gamma  \rangle = \sum_{ij}\mathbf{C}_{ij}\boldsymbol\Gamma_{ij} \\
\mathrm{s. t.}  \quad  & \boldsymbol\Gamma \mathbf{1} = \mathbf{\alpha} \\
&\boldsymbol\Gamma^{\top}\mathbf{1} = \mathbf{\beta}
\end{align*}

- $\boldsymbol C$ is the distance matrix, which contains elements$\Vert x - y \Vert$,
- $\boldsymbol \Gamma$ is the transport matrix, which contains elements $\gamma(x,y)$,
- $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the source and target probability distributions, respectively, of variables $X$ and $Y$.

### OT Linear Programming #2

([Source](https://vincentherrmann.github.io/blog/wasserstein/))
$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
\min_{\mathbf{x}} \ & \mathbf{c}^T \mathbf{x} &  & \ \\
\mathrm{s.t.} \ & \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} & = & \ \mathbf{b} \\
 \  & \mathbf{x} & \geq &\ \mathbf{0}
\end{array}$$

- $\mathbf{c}$ is a vectorization of the distance matrix $\boldsymbol C$,
- $\mathbf{x}$ is a vectorization of the transport matrix  $\boldsymbol\Gamma$,
- while the source and target distributions are $\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The first version is how you naturally think about it in mathematical terms and write in papers. The second version is how you have to reformulate it to actually fit it into canonical LP form (and possibly feed into a solver).

Comment: about reconciling the two, how can it be shown that the constraints in version #1 are a rewording of the constraints in version #2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reconcile both, note that $\bf x$ is obtained by stacking the columns of $\bf \Gamma$. For the cost, $\bf c$ is obtained by stacking the columns of the cost matrix $\bf C$.
Also, let $\mathbb I_n$ be an $n\times n$ identity matrix. Therefore, make:
$$
{\bf A} = \begin{bmatrix}
{\bf 1}_n^\top \otimes \mathbb I_m\\
\mathbb I_n \otimes {\bf 1}_m^\top 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Finally, the constraint ${\bf x}\geq 0$ is the same as the constraint that the transport plan $\bf \Gamma$ must be positive. This can be found in page 38 in the book *Computational Optimal Transport*, by Peyré and Cuturi. The pdf of the book is freely avaiable.

Comment: I know that Program #2 shown in the question appears in *Computational optimal transport*, but do you know if Program #1 does too, or if they make reference to it?

Comment: Yeah, this #1 formulation of the problem is actually much more present throughout the book, while the second one is just briefly mentioned. As you pointed out, most algorithms for solving LP use the second formulation, and that is the only reason (I guess), the authors actually show it.

Comment: if $\boldsymbol c$ contains distances $| x - y|$, how can I reconcile the fact that $\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta\end{bmatrix}$ is just a figurative  representation of $\bar{\boldsymbol{b}} = \begin{bmatrix} \boldsymbol x \\ \boldsymbol y \end{bmatrix}$, where $\alpha$ is by definition $\boldsymbol x$, the source distribution, and $\beta$ is by definition $\boldsymbol y$, the target distribution?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand... I mean, $b$ is a vector containing the marginal distributions. I don't understand what is the $\bar b$.

Comment: It's my version of $\boldsymbol b$ that reflects what $\boldsymbol c$ was computed from: the samples of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, which are $x$ and $y$

Comment: I think I understand your question now. I think your misconception is the following. $\alpha$ is not the vector of coordinates, but the vector of weights. I will edit my answer and provide an example.

Comment: Actually, just take a look at this computational implementation, and this might answer your questions. https://github.com/davibarreira/OptimalTransport.jl/blob/gallery/examples/example_2.ipynb

Comment: thanks for the link. is there a way for me to flatten the example to 1D instead of 2D? it is very similar to Peyre's code which is also 2D http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/gpeyre/numerical-tours/blob/master/python/optimaltransp_1_linprog.ipynb

Comment: To flatten you just need to use coordinates in 1D instead of 2D. Note that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ contain only weights, so they are always a $n\times1$ vectors. While the actual coordinates will be used to construct matrix $C$. Note, $C_{1,1} = |x_1 - y_1|$.

Comment: Did you know that `scipy.stats.wasserstein_distance` does not use linear programming. It's code is in the following link  (which only does 1D). If it's not using LP, how can optimal transport be solved without LP. What method/approach is being used?  https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/aa8ebbc3fc0e8057ae2cbd3255a702dd8f0ab94d/scipy/stats/stats.py#L7887

Comment: If it’s 1D, then there is an actual Monge map, which is given by the composition of the CDF and the inverse CDf

Comment: aren't Monge **transport maps** unable to perform mass-splitting from the source to target distributions, unlike the Kantorovich **transport plan**?

Comment: You are right. But the solution still works (although it will not be a Monge Map). Look on page 32 of Computational Optimal Transport book.

Comment: You just need to use the quantile function and it’s inverse to compute the Wasserstein distance.

Comment: I don't see quantile or inverse `.ppf` functions used in the code for  `wasserstein_distance` though https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3866825/why-doesnt-scipys-wasserstein-distance-use-linear-programming

Comment: For discrete cases you can hard code it. I answered in your question