# Why is the distance matrix in optimal transport always the same, and doesn't actually measure distances between samples?

Tags: statistics, optimization, metric-spaces, linear-programming, optimal-transport

Why does the distance matrix computed in the optimal transport linear programming model always look the same (asides from its size changing with the number of histogram bins) no matter how the source and target distributions might change?

If we really are supposed to be interested in the distances between samples in the source and target distributions, why does optimal transport dumb down this step to a distance comparison of cardinality, that is, the distances between the integer-indices of the source and target distributions, without any imputation of actual sample observations or probabilities?

Matrix D in the image below is the distance matrix, which always shows the same pattern regardless which sample data is thrown in the model:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why does optimal transport dumb down this step to a distance comparison of cardinality, that is, the distances between the integer-indices of the source and target distributions, without any imputation of actual sample observations or probabilities?

The matrix $D$ is completely independent from the input distribution, and element $D_{ij}$ defines how hard it is to move *one unit* of whatever you are moving from location $i$ to location $j$.

The source and target distributions indicate how much should be moved from and to each location. If you decide to move $0.2$ from location $i$ to location $j$, the contribution to the objective function is $0.2D_{ij}$. Let $s_i$ be the amount available at source location $i$, then the contribution of that amount to the objective function is $\sum_j D_{ij} x_{ij}$ where $x_{ij}$ satisfies $\sum_j x_{ij} = s_i$. Therefore, if $s_i$ is large, row $i$ of matrix $D$ is multiplied with (at least some) large coefficients, so this is how cardinality comes into play.

Comment: so am i right that the distance matrix is always the same regardless of data?

Comment: @develarist the distance matrix does not depend on the input or target distribution, but is a piece of data in itself. For example, you could have a river in between positions $i$ and $j$ which affects the cost of moving between $i$ and $j$.

Comment: if the distance matrix is independent of the input and target data, then it is always the same, always looks the same, and is not something calculated whatsoever based on the input and target data. It is just 1's, 2's, 3's minus 1's, 2's, 3's. or we have that all wrong, and only in the example picture above, both the source and target have identical indicies (bin values), whereas in a different example the source could have $[-5,3]$ for its domain, and the target could have $[1,9]$ for a domain, which *would* change the appearance of the distance matrix right?

Comment: That is right. Optimal transport could also be about physical goods, where the sources and targets are cities, which also produces a different picture.

Comment: so if the first "bin" in the source is $-5$, whereas the first bin in the target is $1$, then it makes no sense to calculate the distance between the first sample in the two distributions cardinally as $1-1=0$. Alot of packages default to this, however, and there is no option to adjust this cardinal distance in their function. In textbooks, on the other hand, it is always flouted that Wasserstein distance works irrespective of the two distributions being on different metric spaces. The packages do not implement this ideal for some reason, always giving the same distance matrix

Comment: @develarist it affects the objective value, but not the optimal solution. You can subtract a constant from each row or from each column (so you can also subtract the smallest element from each row/column to have at least one 0) because it changes all feasible transportations equally.

Comment: This is probably the answer I'm looking for. hopefully someone can demonstrate the invariance you're talking about: first with the source and target locations/coordinates aligned (the cardinal default), and second with their locations where they are in their respective datasets

Comment: @develarist it is the premise of the Hungarian algorithm, see https://brilliant.org/discussions/thread/intuition-behind-the-hungarian-algorithm/ for an explanation

Comment: it looks like the Hungarian algorithm is for the Monge formulation, which didn't permit mass-splitting from the source to target distributions, that is, one unit had to go entirely to one target location. Does the "constant-invariance" you described also hold for the Kantorovich formulation, which does allow mass-splitting?

Comment: @develarist perhaps you can answer that question yourself if you understand the argument

Comment: My guess is that the "constant-invariance" still applies in the Kantorovich transport plan as it does in the Monge transport map as long as the source and target histograms are 1D, because of page 32 of Computational Optimal Transport book since someone else commented "the solution still works (although it will not be a Monge Map)" at the following link. Is my reasoning right and corresponds to your  answer? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3905774/different-linear-programming-versions-of-optimal-transport/3913128?noredirect=1#comment8111895_3913128

Comment: It is correct, even in higher dimensions, as long as you subtract a constant either from all costs from a source or from all costs to reach a destination, because the total amount that is transported from a source or to a destination is constant.